# Jshell /env command not allowing to Set More than one Jar file in Classpath

Tags: java, java-11, jshell

Hi I am using JDK11 on windows 10 operating system and Jshell version I am using is 11.0.1.

I am trying to execute the various Jshell commands and got stuck in execution of below commands

I have a sample program which is using the classes from more than one JAR file Employee.jar and spring-context-5.1.3.jar files.

After login to Jshell I am using the below command to set the class path in Jshell but it is throwing the error

```
jshell> /env -class-path D:\JshellClassPath\Employee.jar:D:\JshellClassPath\spring-context-5.1.3.jar
|  File 'D:\JshellClassPath\Employee.jar:D:\JshellClassPath\spring-context-5.1.3.jar' for '--class-path' is not found.
```

if I set only one Jar file and execute the above command it is working fine but why I am not able to set multiple Jar files /env command?

Comment: Try `;` as separator instead of `:`.

Comment: @talex thanks for help . It is working fine now.

Comment: @talex just one question from my side is it possible to copy all these JAR files in folder and directly provide that folder in /env command to avoid mentioning the JAR files in seperatly?

Comment: You can us `*` like `D:\JshellClassPath\*`

Comment: @Thanks once again talex for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows platform you have to use `;` as separator instead of `:`.